# What is the proper way to handle forms in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, webforms, view, controller

Forms + ASP.NET MVC = Confusing for me:

1. **What are the preferred ways to setup your controller action for form posts?**

   - Do I need to specify an attribute that has [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]?
   - Should the controller action take a "FormCollection" or should I use ModelBinders?
   - If I should use ModelBinders, how?
2. **How do I setup the form in the view?**

   - Should I use the Html helpers like Html.BeginForm/Html.EndForm or simply specify the form tag myself?
   - How do you specify the controller and action to be used in a form (with either the Html helpers or with a manual form tag)?

**Can somebody please show me both a simple view with a form ~and~ its corresponding controller action?**

I'm trying to write a form with a single textbox that I can submit to the Home/Create action and pass the string from the textbox to it.

Answer (score 4):

ScottGu's [handling form edit and post scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx) is exactly what you're looking for. There's also [form posting scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx) and even though it was written for preview 5, it's still mostly valid.

Answer (score 0):

The template's AccountController.LogOn and .Register methods along with the corresponding views should give you the simple introduction you need.